# What is the meaning of the phrase "contended even unto death for seven long years?"

Tags: speech

I am reading a speech delivered by John Hossack in 1860. I am posting this question because I would like to know what the phrase in bold means. Hossack is speaking below in response to the prosecution team that accused him of violating the Fugitive Slave Law.

> I go, Sir, to the Constitution of my country: the word slave is not to
> be found. I read, "We, the people of the United States, in order to
> form a more perfect Union, establish justice,"—yes, Sir, establish
> justice—"to promote the general welfare, and to secure the blessings
> of liberty to ourselves and our posterity, so ordain and establish
> this Constitution of the United States of America." These were the men
> who had proclaimed to the world that all men were created equal; that
> they were endowed by their Creator with certain inalienable
> rights—life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness; and **contended
> even unto death for seven long years**.

Why seven years? Does this number have some significance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks about a historical fact rather than an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

“We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their creator with certain inalienable rights, that among these are life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness ...”

This is the most famous passage of the Declaration of Independence, written in 1776 to justify a rebellion against the British Crown; that rebellion (“contention unto death”) resulted in the Treaty of Paris seven years later.

Comment: +1 Though it's implicit in this answer, I'll say explicitly that the "seven long years" were the years of the Revolutionary War.

Answer (score 0):

[Hassock's mansion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hossack_House) was built between 1854-56 and was a 'station' on the 'Underground Railroad' which helped escaped slaves to freedom. The wikipedia entry for [Hassock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hossack) says that during the period when he built his house he 'deepened his connection with the Underground Railroad' which suggests that the abolitionist group in Ottawa, Illinois was in existence before 1854.

It is quite reasonable to imagine that they had been actively assisting escaped slaves from 1853 which would match Hassock's statement that the group had been risking severe consequences (possibly even being killed) for seven years before 1860.

Comment: I'll have to downvote unless you remove. 'It is reasonable to imagine' lacks adequate support, and this question is not about English [metaphorical usage]. OP needs to check historical data.

Comment: Probably belongs in history. But it may be that the 7 years (as he calculates it) of the Revolutionary war establish the Constitution, which has no mention of slavery, thus the Fugitive Slave Laws are unconstitutional.

Comment: @Xanne Good point, I'd not spotted that he was talking about the men who drafted the constitution, I was thinking that he was talking about other Ottawans involved in the Underground Railroad.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll delete it since I'm proved wrong, but I'll wait until Xanne has responded to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

> and contended even unto death for seven long years.

**and contended** = And have been argued and fought over

**even unto death** = even to the extent that people have been killed

**for seven long years.** = for seven years that have been so difficult for everyone that each year appeared to be longer than a normal year.

> Why seven years? Does this number have some significance?

Yes it indicates the length of time (at that point) that the arguments and fighting have been continuing.